# Take a ten minute walk(edit)

Tags: python

I'm pretty new at coding and I am doing a Codewars test in which my code had this results:

Time: 837ms Passed: 1 Failed: 3 Exit Code: 1
Test Results:
Test Passed
should return False
should return False
should return False

I don't know why my code doesn't pass everything but it has passed in the past that I only approve one of the tests I don't know if I'm missing something for my code to try the other tests.

You live in the city of Cartesia where all roads are laid out in a perfect grid. You arrived ten minutes too early to an appointment, so you decided to take the opportunity to go for a short walk. The city provides its citizens with a Walk Generating App on their phones -- every time you press the button it sends you an array of one-letter strings representing directions to walk (eg. ['n', 's', 'w', 'e']). You always walk only a single block in a direction and you know it takes you one minute to traverse one city block, so create a function that will return true if the walk the app gives you will take you exactly ten minutes (you don't want to be early or late!) and will, of course, return you to your starting point. Return false otherwise.

This is my code:

```
def is_valid_walk(walk):
    horizontal = 0
    vertical = 0
    for each in walk:
        if walk == 'n':
            vertical = vertical+1
        elif walk == 's':
            vertical = vertical+1
        elif walk == 'e':
            horizontal = horizontal+1
        elif walk == 's':
            horizontal = horizontal+1
    count = len(walk)
    if vertical == 0 & horizontal == 0 & count == 10:
        return "True"
    else:
        return "False"
```

Thanks for the contributions I changed my code, this is my new code:

def is_valid_walk(walk):

```
horizontal = 0
vertical = 0
for each in walk:
    if walk == 'n':
        vertical = vertical + 1
    elif walk == 's':
        vertical = vertical + 1
    elif walk == 'e':
        horizontal = horizontal + 1
    elif walk == 'w':
        horizontal = horizontal + 1

count = len(walk)

if vertical == 0 and horizontal == 0 and count == 10:
    return True
else:
    return false
```

It passed all the test but with a warning:
 STDERR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in 
    test.expect(not is_valid_walk(['w','e','w','e','w','e','w','e','w','e','w','e']), 'should return False');
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 20, in is_valid_walk
    return false
NameError: name 'false' is not defined

Comment: `if walk == 'n': vertical += 1; elif walk == 's'; vertical += 1` is that what you mean? Shouldn't you subtract one in one direction or the other?

Comment: All the conditions add `1` to `vertical` or `horizontal`. That means that any non-empty `walk` will never allow `vertical` and `horizontal` to be `0`. One condition should add `1` to `vertical` and the other should subtract `1`. The same goes for `horizontal`. Try to fix it and see if it works.

Comment: I think the problem here is you're returning `True` and `False` as strings rather as boolean values. I would guess that the first test case expects an answer of `True`, and any non-emtpy string can be coerced into a boolean value of `True`.

Comment: Also, you may be confusing `each` and `walk` within the loop.

Comment: There are no syntax errors in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'm going to point out some mistakes you've made:

1. "Return true or false"

   you should `return True` or `return False`.
   if you `return "False"` python will still consider it's `True`, since `bool('False') == True`
2. Bitwise and

   you've used `if vertical == 0 & horizontal == 0 & count == 10`. In fact, you should use `and` if you want to use espression and.
3. Logic mistake

   As the comments said, I'm not going to repeat here.

**EDIT**

In your code:

```py
...
else:
    return false
```

should be `return False` (with capital letter). `True` and `False` are keywords in python.

Answer (score 2):

I can give you an easier and short solution :

```
def isValidWalk(walk):
if (walk.count('n') == walk.count('s') and 
    walk.count('e') == walk.count('w') and
    len(walk) == 10):
        return True
return False
```

or

if want more shorter code :

```
def isValidWalk(walk):
return len(walk) == 10 and walk.count('n') == walk.count('s') and walk.count('e') == walk.count('w')
```

just maintain the syntax according to your editor.

Have fun ;)

Answer (score 0):

On top of the other comments, you also have south represented twice. The horizontal 's' should be 'w'.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error you get after your edit is that `False` must be spelled with a capital F.

You also still need to address the errors that have been pointed out in the comments above:

- Currently your whole `for`-loop is not doing anything, because all the conditions within are always false for any expected input. That's because `walk` is supposed to be a list of strings, not a single string, so e.g. `walk == 'n'` is always false. What you mean there is `each == 'n'` instead, because `each` is the variable that is looping through every element of `walk`. It's the same for the other conditions.
- In the south and west conditions, you need `-1` instead of `+1`, as pointed out by @Adam Smith and @Yahia Zakaria above.

Answer (score 0):

I am stuck on this one as well and getting the same error. I would like to point out that the N:S and E:W axes do not need to be discerned. You can just consider the E:W and just another N:S as you are still moving one set away or closer. Try it out and see you can just use a reducer. In JS this works well.

```
function isValidWalk(walk) {
if (!(walk.length === 10)){ return  false }
 const reducer = (pv, cv) =>{
   (cv === 's' || cv === 'e') ? pv -= 1 : pv += 1 
   return pv
   }
const answer =  walk.reduce(reducer, 0) 
  if (answer == 0){
   return  true} 
  else  return false}
```